# Linking errors regarding -fPIC even though all sources are compiled with -fPIC

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I couldn't find a direct answer on Google, and since I haven't done stuff on Linux for a long time hoped to find help here. I am getting a linking error on Ubuntu when building a shared object. The linker tells me I should recompile with `-fPIC` even though I have set `-fPIC` for all source files. The output of `make`:

```
mkdir -p ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi
g++ -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c CentralServerClient.cpp -o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/CentralServerClient.o
CentralServerClient.cpp:4:80: warning: unused parameter ‘pEventListener’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void CCentralServerClient::AddEventListener(ICentralServerClientEventListener* pEventListener)
                                                                            ^
CentralServerClient.cpp:29:83: warning: unused parameter ‘pEventListener’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void CCentralServerClient::RemoveEventListener(ICentralServerClientEventListener* pEventListener)
                                                                               ^
g++ -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c HttpRequest.cpp -o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/HttpRequest.o
g++ -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c HttpResponse.cpp -o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/HttpResponse.o
g++ -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c IOService.cpp -o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/IOService.o
g++ -Wl,-shared -Wl,-v -Wl,-g -o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi.so ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/CentralServerClient.o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/HttpRequest.o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/HttpResponse.o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/IOService.o
collect2 version 4.9.2
/usr/bin/ld -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccZ9RMHe.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. -shared -v -g ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/CentralServerClient.o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/HttpRequest.o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/HttpResponse.o ../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi/IOService.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.25
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `__libc_csu_fini' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target '../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi.so' failed
make: *** [../_Bin/Debug/HttpClientApi.so] Error 1
```

gcc is `gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but does `.so` require `-fPIC` also or not? Because it is the only one that does not have it...

Comment: Not sure, that is why I am asking. If the error message would state relink with fPIC  then I would have zero doubts. And to answer the apparent question why cant I simply try it - I gave up and left the office 5 min ago. But will try that first thing tomorrow.

Comment: What happens if you manually run it again with `-fPIC` (since all object files have been generated)?

Comment: @SergeyA as you can see from the linker invocation I did not. Is that required? I mean must I pass fPIE to linker when compiling with fPIC?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of giving g++ `-Wl,-shared` you should give it `-shared`. The reason is that g++ need to know which crt1.o to use - one suitable for shared libraries (compiled with `-fPIC`, scrt1.o) or one which is not suitable.

When you give `-shared` to g++ it knows to use scrt1.o. But when you pass `-Wl,-shared', g++ doesn't know that you are building shared library - it 'thinks', you are building a normal executable (linker does know what is happening) and asks linker to link with crt1.o. Linker refuses and you have an error.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense:) Will try this tomorrow.